# Querying a json field in mysql using JOOQ

Tags: mysql, json, jooq

I have a transaction table and it has a json type field called "*request*".

```
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default |
| id                  | bigint       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| request             | json         | NO   |     | NULL    |
| response            | json         | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

request has two attributes *currencyCode* and *amount*.

```
{"amount":100000,"currencyCode":"PHP"}
```

I can use following mysql query to fetch these values

```
select json_extract(request, "$.amount") as amount, json_extract(request, "$.currencyCode") as currency from transaction;

| amount | currency |
+--------+----------+
| 100000 | PHP      |
| 100000 | PHP      |
| 100000 | PHP      |
```

I want to get these values using a jooq query something like this.

```
DSL.select(<Tables.TRANSACTION.REQUEST.amount>, <Tables.TRANSACTION.REQUEST.currencyCode>)
.from(Tables.TRANSACTION)
.fetch()
```

I really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using jOOQ 3.14's `JSON_VALUE` support

Starting with jOOQ 3.14, you will be able to use the new built-in standard JSON operator support, e.g. [`JSON_VALUE()`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.14/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/json-functions/json-value-function/). As per the docs:

> This example using jOOQ:
>
> ```java
> jsonValue(val(JSON.json("[1,2]")), "$[*]")
> ```
>
> Translates to the following dialect specific expressions:
>
> ```sql
> ...
> -- MYSQL
> json_extract('[1,2]', '$[*]')
> ```

#### Using plain SQL templating in jOOQ 3.13 and earlier

Whenever jOOQ doesn't support vendor specific functionality out of the box, you can resort to using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/). Just write:

```java
public static Field<String> jsonExtract(Field<?> field, String jsonPath) {
  return DSL.field("json_extract({0}, {1})", String.class, field, DSL.inline(jsonPath));
}
```

Comment: This question was about how to select the data from a field, not from a `val`. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @dougalg: `val(T)` returns `Field<T>`, so why would it matter?

Comment:  Woops. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I have tried to use `DSL.field("json_unquote(json_extract({0}, {1}))", String.class, field, DSL.inline(jsonPath));` with r2dbc but jOOQ seems to have problems extracting the data as string. The fetched result is something like `java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=21 cap=21]`

Comment: It is only working when I add an explicit cast: `DSL.field("json_unquote(json_extract({0}, {1}))", field, DSL.inline(jsonPath)).cast(String.class);`

Comment: @m-kay: your comment is probably not related to this answer. Please ask a new question with all the usual details needed to reproduce the problem (fully self contained example, etc.)